# Updating rows with same id and name in oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

i have a large data inside a table two employees have same name and same id in accident so i want to update one of the two employee so it becomes hard to me do you have any answer or solution

when i write this it updates the two rows

```
update EMPLOYEE 
set id = 2 where Name='ahmed' and id=1
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: Well obviously, what is the problem then?

Comment: I want to update either these two rows

Comment: i have a large data inside a table two employees have same name and same id in accident so i want to update one of the two employee so it becomes hard to me do you have any answer or solusion'

Comment: Do you exactly have 1 employee with exactly 2 equal rows? Or can you have more than 1 employee and/or more than 2 equal rows for employee?

Comment: Please `edit` your question and select the correct `tag`. If you use `MS SQL Server` and not `Oracle`, delete the `oracle` and especially `plsql` tags, and add `sql-server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ROWNUM`

```
update EMPLOYEE 
set id = 2 where Name='ahmed' and id=1 and ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: I wrote for oracle

Comment: For SQL Server you can use this one: `UPDATE TOP (1) EMPLOYEE 
SET id = 2 
WHERE Name = 'ahmed' and id = 1`

Comment: can i use Rownum other rows except row 1